# What is the name of a pressed button?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton array and generate 100 buttons with

```
 for(i=0;i<button.length;i++)
```

but can't figure out what to put as the e.getSource() ie if(e.getSource()==????){} what do I put in the ????. In other words, how do I find what a button created in an array is named in the case of e.getSource.

```
 import javax.swing.*;  
 import javax.swing.border.Border;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class map {
     static int i;
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("D&D");
     public map() {
        int a=0,b=50;
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100,0,1000,600);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);      
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){
            a=a+50;
            if(a>549) {
                b=b+50;
                a=50;
            }
            button[i]= new JButton(SD);
            frame.getContentPane().add(button[i]);
            button[i].setBounds(a, b, 50,50);
            button[i].setFont(new Font("Blackmoor Let", Font.BOLD, 30));
            button[i].setForeground(Color.red);
            button[i].setBorder(border);
            button[i].addActionListener(boardListener);
      }
    }

    ActionListener boardListener = new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.print("\n" +e.getSource());            
            if (e.getSource()==button[i]){              
                System.out.println("hi");
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[]args){
         new map();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's with the freaky form of code indenting you use?  Is it schizophrenic?  BTW - 2 things you should not be doing 1) `frame.setBounds(100,0,1000,600);`  Allow the component to assume the natural size needed to show the children by calling `pack()` once everything is added.  2) 
`frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`  **Use layouts.**

Comment: `button[i].setFont(new Font("Courior", Font.BOLD, 30));`  (polite cough) Spell check!

Comment: In fact, now I see past that horrendous code formatting to the crux of the matter, it seems that font is not "Courior" or even "Courier" but  "Courier New".  The JRE does not find fonts by magic, but by being given the correct name.  ;)

Comment: opps, fix spelling later, but could some one help me with the lists (look at answer below's comments for details)

Comment: *"fix spelling later.."*  Will (consider providing) answer later..

Comment: fixed the spelling, couldn't spell couior so i changed it to Blackmoor Let (know it from a earlier program)

Comment: oh ya, and where can i find a tutorial about code formating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `List<JButton>` rather than a `JButton[]` to hold your buttons, and use

```
 int index = listOfButtons.indexOf(e.getSource())
```

to know the index of the clicked button.

To create and populate the list:

```
List<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>(100);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    JButton button = ...;        
    listOfButtons.add(button);
}
```

If you want to convert an array of JButtons into a `List<JButton>` (but it's not needed here), just use

```
List<JButton> listOfButtons = Arrays.asList(buttons);
```

Comment: I've tired                                                          JButton button[]=new JButton[100];{
      new ArrayList<JButton>(Arrays.asList(array));
      }                                                                    but it doesn't seem to work, could someone help me?

Comment: @user1078803: no need to create an array if it's to transform it into a List afterwards. Use a list from the start. And no need to create a new ArrayList: Arrays.asList(array) is sufficient. See my edited answer.

Comment: thank you so much, make this an answer on it's own and i'd up it but what do I put in the JButton buttons=... (the ...)        and eclipse tells me that The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
 <JButton>, what should I do. p.s I've never heard of lists until just now so explain every thing in great detail, thanks

Comment: Thanks to all answers, I ended up using the List method because it was the most detailed. I'm sorry for asking so many questions, It broke because i didn't copy and past well, and it should've been ArrayList<JButton> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>(100); 
You saved my life thanks. (can't make this an answer because i dont have 100 rep)

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer anyway, and you should program to interfaces: use List<JButton> = new ArrayList<JButton>(100);. That's the best way to do it. You don't care in the rest of your code if it's a LinkedList or an ArrayList. The inmportant thing is that it's a List.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the Button array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < button.length; ++i) {
    if (e.getSource()==button[i]);{
        System.out.println("Button " + i + " pressed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your buttons try this:

```
button[i].setActionCommand(i);
```

And when you get ActionEven e try:

```
e.getActionCommand();
```

The getActionCommand() method returns your i as string so you will have to parse it to int.